# Tuning a query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

What is the best way to tune the below SQL for PostgreSQL which seems to be very costly? Will creating a temporary table gives optimal cost?

```
UPDATE table1
SET    id = qry.crmId
FROM   (
    SELECT b.id AS crmId, a.row
    FROM   table1 AS a INNER JOIN table2 AS b ON lower(a.email) = lower(b.email) AND b.id = (
                SELECT MIN(id)
                FROM   table2
                WHERE  email = b.email AND email IS NOT NULL AND
                created = (
                            SELECT MIN(created)
                            FROM   table2
                            WHERE  email = b.email
                            )
                LIMIT 1
                )
    WHERE a.email IS NOT NULL AND b.id IS NOT NULL AND a.id IS NULL
    ) AS qry
WHERE  table1.row = qry.row;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Strictly speaking the question cannot be answered without also seeing the table definition. We don't know whether `row` is a unique column or which columns can be NULL. The best query also depends on data distribution (Are all / most id in both tables? Etc.) The question needs a minimum of explanation what the purpose of the query is. Either way, the currently accepted answer is *not equivalent* to your query. There is no `table2` and `b.id IS NOT NULL` is treated differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you phrase the query like this:

```
update table1 t11
    set id = (select id
              from table1 t12
              where t12.email = t11.email and
                    t12.id is not null
              order by t12.created
              limit 1
             )
    where id is null and email is not null;
```

Then it can take advantage of indexes on `table1(id)` and `table1(email, created, id)`.

You might want to add a check such as `and exists (select 1 from table1 t12 where t12.email = t11.email and t12.email is not null and t12.id is not null)`.

Comment: will the other check need to be added to inner query?

Comment: @user1595858 . . . No, to the outer query.